# How to remove a sentence using php

Tags: php

I am trying to use strpos to find out if a string exists and then use substr_replace to delete that string.  My code is below:

```
  $title=$item->get_title();
        $stringToFind='Help needed identifying this person in ';
        if(strpos($title,$stringToFind)){
            $title=substr_replace($title,'',0,strlen($stringToFind));
        }
```

However, when I do an echo on the strpos it always returns false when it should be true.  So I'm wondering if strpos doesn't do whitespace or something?  IN which case can someone recommend something?

Comment: i think you can leave the if out, substr_replace does not cause an error when the search string is not found...

Comment: Why not use: `$title = str_replace( $title, "", $title );`

Comment: @hjpotter92 thanks yes, thats worked.  I wasn't aware of that function, only substr_replace, which is why I was trying to specify the start and end of the string to replace

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you give this a shot :

```php
$searchStr = 'Help needed identifying this person in ';
$title = str_replace($searchStr,'',$title);
```

The PHP documentation refers to the `str_replace` function as

> Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string.

If the `$searchStr` does not appear in the `$title` variable then the string will be left alone.
However, if it exists - it will be removed.  You don't need to test if it exists at all.  If you need to test whether a change has been made or not you could compare the length of the two strings using [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) or [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) depending on your encoding.

Example input/outputs :

CONSTANT - `$searchStr = 'Help needed identifying this person in ';`

```
// A match is found - string is changed
IN -> Help needed identifying this person in Timbuktu
OUT -> Timbuktu

IN -> Help needed identifying this person in Zimbabwe
OUT -> Zimbabwe

IN -> Help needed identifying this person in Netanya
OUT -> Netanya

// A match is not found - string remains the same
IN -> Stack Overflow is a programming Q & A site that’s free.
OUT -> Stack Overflow is a programming Q & A site that’s free.

IN -> We don’t run Stack Overflow. You do.
OUT -> We don’t run Stack Overflow. You do.
```

Comment: Which is the $title value? An example is that if $title is equal "Help" , the strpos function is returned 0, and php 0 == false. Use !== false.

Comment: See that I didn't use `strpos` in my solution.  I've made an edit to highlight that though - thank you.  The values of `$title` in the examples are first the `IN` and then after `str_replace` become `OUT`

Comment: @Lix brilliant thank you.  That's exactly what I am using it for as well, just to get the area.  I wasn't aware of the str_replace, only substr_replace.

Answer (score 1):

Is the searched string on position 0? You probably need to use `===` comparisons, because the following is true in php:

```
0 == false // true (automatically casted)
0 === false //false (type-sensitive comparison)
```

So try

```
$title=$item->get_title();

if(strpos($title,'Help needed identifying this person in ') ===false){
        $title=substr_replace($title,'',0,strlen($title));
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `===` in your example?

Answer (score 0):

strpos() return a numeric value or false on error. In this case it's returning 0 because that is the position it's finding the string. You need to use

```
if(strpos($title, $string) !== false) { ...
```

Comment: yes, well noticed!  I thought 0 was false, but yes as you say it's at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

If the sentence is at the beginning of the string, strpos will return 0. When casted to a boolean 0 is equal to false.

Therefore to stop this problem you will need to do a strict comparison. I.E.:

```
$title=$item->get_title();
if(strpos($title,$needle) !==false)
{
    $title=substr_replace($title,'Help needed identifying this person in ',0,strlen($title));
}
```

Another possible problem is that strpos is case sensitive. And 1 upper or lowercase letter will throw everything off. So to prevent this you should probably use `stripos`.